# Collecting data in same query

Tags: c#, sql

I need to fetch the data according to date with a single query. and display the data in c#

I have tried the following query to fetch record

" Select Distinct Date,News From news order by Date "

Result of this query:

```
  Date           News

2/3/2014        Jeo news
2/4/2014        Aaj news
2/4/2014        aag
2/4/2014        express news
2/5/2014        dunya news
```

The problem is : How can i display the this record in c# according to this format?

```
2/3/2014
Jeo news

2/4/2014
Aaj news
aag
express news

2/5/2014
dunya news
```

Here is my c# code

```
 try
        {
            da.Fill(dt);
            for(int i=0; i<dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
            Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i]["News"].ToString()) ;

            Console.Write("\n");
            }
            Console.Read();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
```

Comment: If you can, use LINQ and do a group by on the Date field and then iterate the keys and do your console.writelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to throw this out there, you are ordering by `Date`, so you could take the route of just comparing the last date to the current one:

```
var olddate = DateTime.MinValue;
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    var newdate = DateTime.Parse(dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString());
    if (newdate != olddate)
    {
         Console.WriteLine();
         Console.WriteLine(newdate.ToShortDateString());
    }
    Console.WriteLine(dt.Rows[i]["News"].ToString());

    olddate = newdate;
 }
 Console.Read();
```

this'll produce exactly your desired output

Answer (score 1):

You can use [LINQ To DataSet/DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386977%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You can `GroupBy` on Date and then select News as List like:

```
var result = dt.AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(r=> r.Field<DateTime>("Date"))
                .Select(grp => new 
                {
                    Date =  grp.Key,
                    News = grp.Select(r=> r.Field<string>("News")).ToList()
                });
```

Later for output you can use:

```
foreach (var item in result.OrderBy(r=> r.Date))
{
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",
      item.Date, Environment.NewLine, string.Join(Environment.NewLine,item.News)));
}
```

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas, what is not working what are the exact error/exception messages you are getting ? Also what is the type of your Date field ? is it a string or DateTime type column ?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of the last date you printed. When it changes print the new date.

```
string previousDate = String.Empty;

for( int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    string currentDate = dt.Rows[i]["Date"].ToString();

    if( previousDate != currentDate )
    {
        Console.WriteLine( currentDate );
    }

    Console.WriteLine( dt.Rows[i]["News"].ToString() );
}
```